# Capybara Webkit runtime warning: Class is implemented in both

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, webkit, capybara-webkit

I get a slew of warnings from webkit when I run `rspec`.  I am using `capybara-webkit` and `qt` installed from `brew`.   I sure would love to fix these.  Thanks for your help.

**Warnings like: "Implemented in both"**

```
objc[97388]: Class WebCoreMovieObserver is implemented in both /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[97388]: Class WebCoreSharedBufferData is implemented in both /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[97388]: Class WebVideoFullscreenWindow is implemented in both /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[97388]: Class WebVideoFullscreenController is implemented in both /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[97388]: Class WebVideoFullscreenHUDWindowController is implemented in both /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[97388]: Class WebVideoFullscreenHUDWindow is implemented in both /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[97388]: Class WebWindowFadeAnimation is implemented in both /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[97388]: Class WebWindowScaleAnimation is implemented in both /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

EDIT: I'm only interested in answers that involve `qt` installed from `brew`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to download and use the pre-built version of Qt library.

I was trying to build using MacPorts and had difficulty. Qt site have prebuilt binary for that. In my case, it's working fine.

I've been using capybara-webkit with pre-built Qt for nearly a year, without issues on MacOS X 10.6 and 10.7

Comment: I thought `brew` used a pre-built `qt`.  How is `brew`'s `qt` different from your `qt`?  Please note that I am not using MacPorts.

Comment: I'm not using brew so I may misunderstand how brew configuration work, but according to 

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/qt.rb

It's configuring and making it.

Comment: Doesn't explain why the error occurs, but I suspect that it does indeed get rid of the warnings so awarding the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies... this belongs as a comment on @shigeya's answer.

The pre-built Qt binary does not fix this problem.  Installed 4.8.2 just now, along with `brew remove --force qt`, resulting in:

```
objc[67716]: Class WebCoreMovieObserver is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[67716]: Class WebCoreSharedBufferData is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[67716]: Class WebVideoFullscreenWindow is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[67716]: Class WebVideoFullscreenController is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[67716]: Class WebVideoFullscreenHUDWindowController is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[67716]: Class WebVideoFullscreenHUDWindow is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[67716]: Class WebWindowFadeAnimation is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[67716]: Class WebWindowScaleAnimation is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Comment: Also, while this does not answer the question, I found that switching from capybara-webkit to [poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist) (based on brew installed phantomjs which uses webkit) made the warnings go away.